# Does Android SDK (Android Development Tools ) alter the Java SDK?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to develop a Windows application using Java SDK and eclipse, also I want to develop an Android app while using the same PC and eclipse. Is it possible to do both as I`m not sure if I set up eclipse and install the Android Development Tools (ADT) will I still be able to develop the Windows application at the same time???

Comment: It exapnds upon what Java has.  It adds the classes for various items, how everything interact etc.  On the backend its all java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download the Android Development Tools from the Android website.


The Android Development Tools is nothing more than Eclipse modified with the ADT Plug in preinstalled.


In it, you have the option to create both Android projects and plain old Java projects.


So, downloading the Android Development Tools alone will give you everything you need.


If you already had Eclipse set up, installing the ADT yourself into it will not take away any functionality from Eclipse, it will just add ADT functionality on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

No - all ADT does is use the existing JDK environment :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not alter it.

You will have the Android SDKs on their own folders and has nothing to do with JDK.